# How to localize Tidestone Formula One control in Chinese?

Tags: localization, vb6, chinese-locale

In our VB6 component, we are using "Formula One OLE Control" which was created by company named "Tidestone Technologies, Inc..

We need to support Chinese characters, as part of localization activity of our software. However, unfortunately there is lack of documentation for this control and the company website just does not exists.

Tried out below code and F1Book just continue to display Chinese characters as question mark.

```
F1Book1.SetDefaultFontEx "Arial", F1GB2312CharSet, 12
F1Book1.SetFontEx "Arial Unicode MS", F1ChineseBig5CharSet, 12, False, False, False, False, OLE_COLOR, False, False
```

Any help for this is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Have you set your PC settings to Chinese (somewhere in control panel regional options, something like "language for non-Unicode programs") ? You may need to install East Asian fonts - ASFAICR it will ask you to do this when you change the "language for non-unicode programs"

Comment: Merely changing PC settings to Chinese doesn't work, the Chinese version of Windows OS itself needs to be installed to make this work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chinese version of Windows OS itself needs to be installed for localization to work correctly for Tidestone Formula one control.

Comment: Weird. Can't think why. I've never used Tidestone control but we have VB6 programs with a variety of controls , localized into Chinese that work fine & dont require Chinese OS.

Comment: Yes, looks strange to me as well. However, this worked only with Chinese OS. Even the user input worked correctly for Chinese characters, and this do not work on English OS for Chinese characters.